# My wifi gets extremely slow until I reconnect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb

I am on Windows 8.1 and using a USB wireless adapter to connect to my Wifi router. Every time I connect, I get a couple minutes of normal internet usage and then everything just slows down to a crawl. The wifi doesn't drop, I'm still connected, I can still play online for example, but it feels like I can't connect to anything after that window.

My flatmate doesn't have this issue (same wifi network), and I have tried multiple usb wireless adapters with the exact same result. So I'm pretty confident it's something on my computer.

Any ideas?

PS: Another thing I should add is that I completely reinstalled Windows and had the same issue with the default configuration and nothing installed.

Comment: "I completely reinstalled Windows " - This indicates it is indeed a hardware issue. We talking about a USB 2 or USB 3 device adapter?

Comment: USB 2. But as I said, I've tried another USB adapter (from another manufacturer) and I had the exact same issue. The drivers are also up to date and very recent (late 2014, for Win8.1)

Comment: Does your computer have its own adapter built-in by chance?  If you tried a bunch of USB 2.0 devices it could be a USB bandwidth issue.  What other devices do you have connected?

Comment: My mobo doesn't have a built-in adapter. I generally have my gaming mouse, a standard keyboard and my USB headphones. Rarelly I also have my phone charging. My mobo is a Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H.

Comment: Are you using the god awful `GIGABYTE On/Off Charge technology` feature?  I say god awful because ASUS has a similar feature and it was causing my camera to be unusable by any program.

Comment: I don't think so. I'll have to check when I get home but I know for sure that I haven't turned that feature on, so I'd say no unless it is turned on by default.

Comment: I suggest backing up your UEFI settings then restoring the default.  Additionally if an update has been released go ahead and update it.

Comment: There's the outside possibility that it's QoS/WMM in the router, prioritising poorly. I'd at least try rebooting or even factory resetting that & see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling power management on your USB ports.  You can do this from Device Manager.  It could be that your motherboard is being too aggressive with the power savings.